# Meta-meta: synonymize [delete]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, synonym-request

The [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) tag seems like it's fairly pointless to me. It has the same meaning as *at least one* of these tags:

- [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions)
- [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers)
- [vote-to-delete](/questions/tagged/vote-to-delete)

Can it be synonymized with one of those? I'd do it myself, but I don't have the rep needed.

Comment: [We have a tag for talking about MSE on MSE itself.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta)

Comment: @dorukayhan I don't think I've ever seen a better definition of a meta-tag.

Comment: Actually no need for the [tag:meta] tag here in my opinion, the generic synonym request tag is enough since it's clear it's asking only about the site where it's posted. All others (about SO before the MSO/MSE split) should be closed.

Comment: @Sha my God, we're having a discussion about a meta meta tag, on a meta meta Meta question.

Comment: haha, too much meta. Meta overflow... :D

Comment: Anyway, I think that the [tag:delete] tag better be burninated, replaced with the relevant tag instead in all questions. Unless there are questions about delete in general, which would likely be too broad anyway.

Comment: @Shadow It's now burninated.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, it appears that the general consensus based on the tag wiki and what others were doing was to remove the tag.

As of today, there were 25 questions that were using it, and I've gone ahead and removed it from all of them.

This should no longer be an issue.